# Find the values of p that makes the series converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Find the values of p that makes the following series converge:
>   $$ 
> \Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\Bigl)^p + \Bigl(\frac{1{}\cdot{}3}{2{}\cdot{}4}\Bigl)^p  + \Bigl(\frac{1{}\cdot{}3{}\cdot{}5}{2{}\cdot{}4{}\cdot{}6}\Bigl)^p +  \ldots
> $$

I tried to use **Raabe's test** but couldn't find $\lim_{n\to\infty} {n\biggl(\Bigl(\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}\Bigl)^p - 1}\biggl)$

Comment: Hint. Write $x = 1/(2n+1)$ so that $$n\left(\left(\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}\right)^p-1\right) = \frac{1-x}{2} \cdot \frac{(1+x)^p - 1}{x}. $$ Can you proceed from here?

Comment: @SangchulLee This substitution doesn't remove the indeterminacy.

Comment: @Allawonder I agree, and that is the limitation of Rabee's test. I personally prefer to solving this by the comparison with $\sum_{n\geq 1} 1/n^{p/2}$.

Comment: Computing the limit of $(1-x)/2$ should be easy, and the second fraction should be recognizable as a derivative....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to find $\lim_{n\to\infty} {n\biggl(\Bigl(\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}\Bigl)^p - 1}\biggl)$ you can put

$\dfrac{2n+2}{2n+1}=1+\dfrac{1}{2n+1}=1+t\iff n=\dfrac{1-t}{2t}$ then your expression becomes
$$\lim_{t\to0}\left(\dfrac{1-t}{2t}\right)((1+t)^p-1)=\lim_{t\to0} \dfrac{(1+t)^p-1}{\frac{2t}{1-t}}$$
You can apply now Hôpital's Rule so you can find

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {n\biggl(\Bigl(\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}\Bigl)^p - 1}\biggl)=\dfrac p2$$